# What's the difference between a ternary operation and this alternative?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know why the following two expressions return the same result i.e. when `val_bool` is always a boolean [`true` or `false`]:

```
('oninput' in document.documentElement && !val_bool) && 'first result' || 'second result';
```

and

```
('oninput' in document.documentElement && !val_bool) ? 'first result' : 'second result';
```

If you open the console and run the following:

```
var val_bool = true;
('oninput' in document.documentElement && !val_bool) && 'first result' || 'second result';
```

`second result` is output. The same result is output when I make a change to ternary:

```
var val_bool = true;
('oninput' in document.documentElement && !val_bool) ? 'first result' : 'second result';
```

I'm not familiar with the mechanism with which the first logical expression resolves its result.

Comment: Related reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Have you used a dev console to test the two statements? They don't behave the same

Comment: Also, you might be getting downvotes because it's not completely clear what you don't understand. I don't think it's necessarily your *fault* (you don't know what you don't know) but it does make the question difficult to answer. Do you already understand the mechanics of boolean logic operators and how short circuiting works? Do you understand how logic operators in JS cast their operands as either "truthy" or "falsy"?

Comment: To be clear about the downvotes, as I downvoted: [You haven't shown that you've done enough research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418). If you look up documentation on how the various logical operators work in JavaScript, you'll have your answer.

Comment: In the first expression `&&` pair evaluates first, then the result evaluates `||` with the last value. On the other hand, ternary expression returnes a value according to evaluated left expression (left from `?`). Run this https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/L838153z/ and look at the console output - in many cases these lines of code are not equal.

Comment: @zzzzBov Honestly, I don't understand the down-voting, but ok. Yes, I tried both in the Chrome console and I get the same result. I tried searching online for ternary alternatives and shorthands, but I guess would have been more effective if I knew exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks. Bookmarked.

Comment: @wostex Thanks. Yes, ternary is straightforward, no issues there. Can you post this as an answer I have a few follow-up questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ternary expression `x ? y : z` the first part is evaluated as boolean and the appropriate value returns.

In another line of code `x && y || z` things are different: it's basically 2 expressions instead of 1.

This link is useful here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

We can see, that `&&` and `||` have left-to-rigth associativity, which means the left part is evaluated first. The following lines are equal:

```
x && y || z
(x && y) || z
```

Expression `x && y` is evaluated first, and `x && y || z` becomes `result(x,y) || z`.

Example when results differ while inputs are the same:

```js
const logical = (x, y, z) => x && y || z;
const ternary = (x, y, z) => x ? y : z;

console.log(
  logical(1, 0, 1) // 1 && 0 || 1 => 0 || 1 => __ 1 __
)

console.log(
  ternary(1, 0, 1) // if (1) then 0; otherwise 1 => __ 0 __ (Boolean(1) === true)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I found this article on [logical operators](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md#operators--and-). Under *Operators `||` and `&&`* I found this statement: "The result of a `||` or `&&` expression is always the underlying value of one of the operands, not the (possibly coerced) result of the test." I had always been think in terms of the  evaluation as boolean, and not the underlying values...

Comment: After looking at some of the examples, it's becoming much clearer now. Will post answer just to resolve the actual question I posted.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this for posterity.

I found a gem of a quote on an article on [Logical Operators](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md#operators--and-). Somewhere under **Operators || and &&**, one paragraph reads:

> The result of a `||` or `&&` expression is always the underlying value of
>   one of the operands, not the (possibly coerced) result of the test.

It turns out I've been looking at things from the point of view of the evaluation, as opposed to the underlying value.

So my initial question had the following expression:

```
('oninput' in document.documentElement && !val_bool) && 'first result' || 'second result';
```

Let's replace the operands with simple variables:

```
var a = true;
var b = true;
var c = 'first result';
var d = 'second result';

(a && !b) && c || d;
```

Firstly, `(a && !b)` will evaluate to `false`, because `a` is `true` and `!b` is `false` and `true && false` is `false`.

Secondly, that `false` result will evaluate with `c` (`(false) && c`). Again, we end up with `false` because `c` will evaluate to a string (`true`), and `false && true` is `false`.

Finally, the result of `false` will evaluate with `d`, only this time the operator is `||` and the evaluation of `false || true` is `true`. However, it's not the evaluation that will be returned, but the underlying value, which is `second result`.

Of course, things will change when I update the original value of `b` from `true` to `false`. Everything to the left of `||` evaluates to `true`, so when you evaluate `true || true` you get `true`, but which `true` is the question. It's the `true` on the left of `||`, because if we evaluated `'a' || 'b'`, the result would be 'a'.

All tolled, it's not equivalent to the ternary operator in function, but the results for the two specific expression [if the variable types remain the same] should be the identical.